# Powepoint VBA AddPicture - Grant File Access

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a dynamic presentation. The presentation will showcase multiple projects, and those projects are shown as thumbnails (in grid) on a slide. Those thumbnails are added already in the slide. Once you click on a thumbnail, it will take you to the next slide loading 5 dynamically called images (via code - .AddPicture).

Now, I got that part nailed down. works perfectly. However, once I share the folder to someone, or even move the folder to a different location in my drive, I get a message that I need to Grant Access to a file. Which is annoying.

Please take note that:

1. I made sure I grabbed the correct path to the file
2. I made sure to check if the user is a mac-user or windows-user using "if Mac"
3. I've tried:

- Updating the filename/path of the linked picture
- creating a new instance of a linked shape

here's a very simple test code I did (file path is for a mac-user):

```
Dim tgtSlide As Slide
Dim prj As Shape

Sub thumbClick()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim picPath As String

    Set sld = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide
    Set tgtSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(sld.SlideIndex + 1)

    'get the presentation save path first
    picPath = ActivePresentation.Path
    'define the image full path
    picPath = picPath & "/PRJ1-IMG1.jpg"

    'add a linked image/shape to target slide
    Set prj = tgtSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(picPath, msoTrue, msoTrue, Left:=50, Top:=50)
    prj.LinkFormat.Update

    'goes to the target slide
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (tgtSlide.SlideIndex)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem is more with the share and file permissions than with the code, no?

Comment: Just a hint, not a solution for your problem: You can use `Application.PathSeparator` instead of hard coding `/` or `\ ` - so code would work on Windows and Mac

Comment: Thanks for that wonderful tip @FunThomas

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I'm not entirely sure. I'm just moving the folder in the same computer to test, and still I get the message.

Comment: Office for Mac is sandboxed. That's why the messages appear. Here is Ron de Bruin's page on this issue: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm Though he is writing about Excel for Mac, the solutions are nearly identical for all Office for Mac 2016 and 2019 programs.

Comment: ```Application.PathSeparator``` exists in Word VBA, but not the PowerPoint version.

Comment: @JohnKorchok, that looks promising. So you think with a windows based computer, I won't be encountering this message?

Comment: Thank you by the way @JohnKorchok

Comment: @Louie, yes, it's a Mac-only problem.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the missing Application.PathSeparator in PPT, you can do this instead:

```
Dim PATHSEP as String
#If Mac Then
  PATHSEP = "/"
#ELSE
  PATHSEP = "\"
#End If
```

Then use PATHSEP in your code when you need the path separator character